# Retrofit2/RxJava2, valve(), FlowableTransformers.valve not working

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I tried to make a shorter code of what I have , but it seems not enough to make it readable so I ended up with the following:

```
    Flowable
            .defer (return new outer observable upon subscribing)
            .retryWhen ( -> 
                          Flowable.flatMap throwable when recieve a 400
                                   valve.onNext(false)
                                    -> Flowable.defer ( return new Network_A_Observable)
                                           .retryWhen ( ->
                                                 Flowable.flatmap throwable when receive 500)

                                                          valve.onNext(true)

                        )
            .compose(flowable valve (i intentionally put a false here))
            .subscribe(new subscriber)
```

This is the very short version of my long-non-lambda code that performs a series of network calls and retrying appropriately on certain conditions.

I have no problems with retrying and emitting a new outer observable for each retry(as this was solved on my other post, but not sure if it has something to do with my current issue), now I noticed that when I perform, say, 2 asynchrounous network calls, it returns two different values, although those two values are valid, and ofcourse the stream of observable works as expected and that was what I intended to do(retry when some error happens), now I realize that I should "PAUSE" the next stream of calls, searching like "**how to pause an observable**, until I found **FlowableTransformer.valve()**, which is available on RxJava2Extensions, I ran a code snippet from a blog where it pauses/continues a stream, but when I tried it on the above code, event if the **valve** is set to **false**, it keeps on finishing the whole stream of flowable.

Am i missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only time valve() terminates eagerly when there is an error, even if paused. A runnable example would be great with your issue.

Comment: thanks @akarnokd for the comment, I just stepped back a bit, and realize some flaws on the design I created, seems liked i need to re-design some part of it, valve() may or may not help for the meantime, anyway, thanks!